# parallax effect, with fixed background

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I have div with `background: url('some/path') no-repeat 50% 0 fixed;` property set.

My parallax effect is working ok, however because of `fixed`, image position became relative to `viewport`, which is expected behavior.

But because of this my background image went **up** from it's `div` container(which is positioned relatively bellow some header, with navigation), and thus not showing in it's complete `height`*(talking about image not showing in its complete heIght, not the div itself)*, but `height - header.height`.

One solution would be to have my background image higher for that amount of difference.

Is there some better way of solving this, for example what one would do then, if he wanted parallax effect on an image in the middle of the page? Making image that tall in that case is very impractical. Am I misssing something?

something like this, in it's simplest form, just to have better idea.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3f8fedf4f6dfcac6607

Comment: If possible, can post `html`, `css`, `js` ? Thanks